# Check if object contains value from array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I filter Objects based on value from another array
the object is as follows:

```
const myJson = {

    "2020-01-10": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "region": "MH",
        "category": "demo",
        "country": "India",
        "descp": "due date for filing GSTR-7",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-10",
        "previousdate": null
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "region": "MH2",
        "category": "demo",
        "country": "India2",
        "descp": "due date for filing GSTR-7",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-10",
        "previousdate": null
      }
    ],
    "2020-01-28": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "region": "GJ",
        "category": "test",
        "country": "India",
        "descp": "GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-28",
        "previousdate": null
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "region": "MH",
        "category": "test",
        "country": "India",
        "descp": "GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-28",
        "previousdate": null
      }
    ]
}
```

and my region array consists of

```
regionArr=['MH','MH2'].
```

I want to filter the above object by checking the whether the regionArr elements are mentioned in any of the object for the key region using lodash.
I tried

```
._every(this.regionArr, el =>
          ._includes(event.region, el)
);
```

but it's not working.
I'm expecting an output like this

```
const myJson = {

    "2020-01-10": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "region": "MH",
        "category": "demo",
        "country": "India",
        "descp": "due date for filing GSTR-7",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-10",
        "previousdate": null
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "region": "MH2",
        "category": "demo",
        "country": "India2",
        "descp": "due date for filing GSTR-7",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-10",
        "previousdate": null
      }
    ],
    "2020-01-28": [

      {
        "id": 3,
        "region": "MH",
        "category": "test",
        "country": "India",
        "descp": "GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-28",
        "previousdate": null
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this question has nothing to do with vue, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

This function iterates an object with [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues), and use [`_.intersectionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersectionWith) to filter the array from the object, with a 2nd array of values, and uses a `comparator` function to match items:

```js
const fn = (obj, arr, comparator) => _.mapValues(
  obj,
  v => _.intersectionWith(v, arr, comparator)
)

const myJson = {"2020-01-10":[{"id":1,"region":"MH","category":"demo","country":"India","descp":"due date for filing GSTR-7","applicableto":"","duedate":"2020-01-10","previousdate":null},{"id":2,"region":"MH2","category":"demo","country":"India2","descp":"due date for filing GSTR-7","applicableto":"","duedate":"2020-01-10","previousdate":null}],"2020-01-28":[{"id":3,"region":"GJ","category":"test","country":"India","descp":"GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India","applicableto":"","duedate":"2020-01-28","previousdate":null},{"id":3,"region":"MH","category":"test","country":"India","descp":"GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India","applicableto":"","duedate":"2020-01-28","previousdate":null}]}

const regionArr = ['MH','MH2']

const result = fn(myJson, regionArr, (a, b) => a.region === b)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you want to support multiple, you'll need to add a comparator function for each array. Pass tuples of [array, comparator], and collect them to an array of `filters` using rest params. Reduce the array of filters, and use the current array from the object (`v`) as the initial value. On each iteration intersect the current array (`acc`) with the the filter array, using the comparator.

```js
const fn = (obj, ...filters) => _.mapValues(
  obj,
  v => filters.reduce((acc, [arr, comparator]) => 
    _.intersectionWith(acc, arr, comparator)
  , v)
)

const myJson = {"2020-01-10":[{"id":1,"region":"MH","category":"demo","country":"India","descp":"due date for filing GSTR-7","applicableto":"","duedate":"2020-01-10","previousdate":null},{"id":2,"region":"MH2","category":"demo","country":"India2","descp":"due date for filing GSTR-7","applicableto":"","duedate":"2020-01-10","previousdate":null}],"2020-01-28":[{"id":3,"region":"GJ","category":"test","country":"India","descp":"GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India","applicableto":"","duedate":"2020-01-28","previousdate":null},{"id":3,"region":"MH","category":"test","country":"India","descp":"GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India","applicableto":"","duedate":"2020-01-28","previousdate":null}]}

const regionArr = ['MH','MH2']
const categoryArr = ['demo']

const result = fn(
   myJson,
   [regionArr, (a, b) => a.region === b],
   [categoryArr, (a, b) => a.category === b]
 )

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks buddy, but what if I have two arrays, ```regionArr = ['MH','MH2'] and categoryArr = ['demo']``` now how do i filter the objects based on both the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a lodash solution but plain JS, hope it helps.

```js
const myJson = {
    "2020-01-10": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "region": "MH",
        "category": "demo",
        "country": "India",
        "descp": "due date for filing GSTR-7",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-10",
        "previousdate": null
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "region": "MH2",
        "category": "demo",
        "country": "India2",
        "descp": "due date for filing GSTR-7",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-10",
        "previousdate": null
      }
    ],
    "2020-01-28": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "region": "GJ",
        "category": "test",
        "country": "India",
        "descp": "GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-28",
        "previousdate": null
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "region": "MH",
        "category": "test",
        "country": "India",
        "descp": "GSTR-11 Return for details of goods and services purchased in India",
        "applicableto": "",
        "duedate": "2020-01-28",
        "previousdate": null
      }
    ]
}


const findByRegion = (json, regionArray) => {
  return Object.entries(json).reduce((acc, [periodKey, periodValue]) => {
      const filteredByRegion = periodValue.filter(item => regionArray.includes(item.region))
      if (filteredByRegion.length) {
        return {
          ...acc,
          [periodKey]: filteredByRegion
        }
      }
      return acc
  }, {})
}


console.log(
  findByRegion(myJson, ['MH', 'MH2'])
)
```

Comment: OP has an array of regions to check - `regionArr`, not a single value.

Comment: I am new to js. I have edited my question. Do check.

Comment: @sheetaldharerao got you buddy, edited the answer, please check